# Are Luke 7:1-10 and John 4:46-54 describing the same historic event?

Tags: john, jesus, luke, contradiction

Both events relative to Capernaum while Jesus was travelling.  In both cases it was remote healing.  Both involve officials.  However, there were many differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the two incidents are similar is some respects is beyond dispute.  However, there are too many differences:

- Luke 7 has a centurion; John 4 it is a royal official
- Luke 7 it is a servant; John 4 it is a son
- Luke 7 has the centurion send Jewish elders to inquire of Jesus; John 4 has the official himself inquire.
- In Luke 7 we have Jesus performing many miracles previously such as exorcism and multiple healings in Luke 4, more healings in Luke 5; In John 4 it is Jesus' second miracle.
- In Luke 7 the message says - "I am unworthy to have you under my roof"; In John 4 the official begs Jesus to come to the house
- In Luke 7 Jesus begins to travel to the house; In John 4 Jesus makes no such move
- In Luke 7 we have the generosity of the centurion extolled by the Jews; there is no such message in John 4.

... and so forth.

They appear quite different events.

Comment: I was starting to wonder about needing to answer this if no one started going through all the details.  The reason for the question is some have tried to say the two are the same and claimed the royal official was a centurion.  Basically there were far more differences than similarities.

Answer (score 3):

They're not the same. The former says he was in Capernaum, the latter says he was in Cana, which was not Capernaum(cf. Jhn 2:11-12). John's account of it is unique, Luke's is paralleled in Matthew 8. The latter also likely took place a few months before that(Jhn 4:35,6:4).